# How can I add text below my carousel image? I used View Pager for the carousel

Tags: android-studio, android-viewpager, carousel, android-linearlayout, androidimageslider

This is what I have now

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/carouselContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_gravity="center" /* Apa yang harus saya tambahkan untuk teks juga? */
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
```

[image]

I want the image and text to slide at the same time. How can I do it?

Comment: add them both in the same layout like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, or another your favorite. And apply slider code to the layout instead of imageView.